# Sprite movement - restrict on particular area?

Tags: android, andengine

i m having an animated sprite moved using path modifier and i want to restrict that sprite is not suppose to move on particular pixel color. so i tried to use get pixel and color but i cant able to find the color code of that color. can any one help me how to do that in andengine 2.0?

```
  int width = src.getWidth();
      int height = src.getHeight();
      // create output bitmap
      Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());
      // color information
      int A, R, G, B;
      int pixel;
      int px;
      px = src.getPixel(CAMERA_WIDTH / 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2);
      R = Color.red(px);
      G = Color.green(px);
      B = Color.blue(px);
      int colblck = Color.rgb(R, G, B);
      Log.e("Tag","Color code for center " + colblck);
      // scan through all pixels
      for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
       for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
        // get pixel color
        pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);

        // get color on each channel
        // A = Color.alpha(pixel);
        R = Color.red(pixel);
        G = Color.green(pixel);
        B = Color.blue(pixel);

        String cd = "" + 00 + 00 + 00;

        bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
```

Comment: Can you please clarify a little more? What is `src`, a `Bitmap`? Have you tried logging `R` `G` and `B` each time? Do they have values? What specifically is happening?